# EF Core One-To-Many Edit ModelState.IsValid False

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I've got an `Asset` model class that can have many `AssetAliases`.

When I try to edit my `Asset`, I'm hitting `ModelState.IsValid= False` on my `AssetAliases`.

Asset model class:

```
public partial class Asset
{
    public int AssetId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Asset Name")]
    public string? AssetName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Assets Aliases")]
    public virtual List<AssetsAlias> AssetsAliases { get; set; }
                                   = new List<AssetsAlias>();

    //... MANY MORE ATTRIBUTES
}
```

`AssetAlias` model class:

```
public partial class AssetsAlias
{
    public int AssetAliasId { get; set; }
    public int AssetId { get; set; }

    public string AssetAliasName { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual Asset Asset { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Relevant `DBContext` code

```
public virtual DbSet<Asset> Assets { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<AssetsAlias> AssetsAliases { get; set; }

modelBuilder.Entity<AssetsAlias>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.AssetAliasId).HasName("PK_Asset_Aliases");

            entity.ToTable("Assets_Aliases");

            entity.Property(e => e.AssetAliasId).HasColumnName("AssetAliasID");
            entity.Property(e => e.AssetAliasName)
                .HasColumnName("AssetAlias"); ;
            entity.Property(e => e.AssetId).HasColumnName("AssetID");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Asset).WithMany(p => p.AssetsAliases)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.AssetId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Assets_Aliases_Assets");
        }
    );
```

`Edit.cshtml.cs`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
{
    if (id == null || _context.Assets == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    //var asset =  await _context.Assets.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.AssetId == id);

    var asset = await _context.Assets
                              .Where(m => m.AssetId == id)
                              .Include(m => m.AssetsAliases)
                              .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    if (asset == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    Asset = asset;

    return Page();
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    _context.Attach(Asset).State = EntityState.Modified;

    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!AssetExists(Asset.AssetId))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return RedirectToPage("/");
}

private bool AssetExists(int id)
{
    return (_context.Assets?.Any(e => e.AssetId == id)).GetValueOrDefault();
}
```

Model state:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're using EF entity classes as Web API DTOs. Don't do that. EF Entity classes are not DTOs.

Comment: @Dai this is a .NET Core Web App.  The models were scaffolded DB-first.  I also scaffolded the CRUD Views, but I've made some customizations to both the models and the CRUD Views trying to accommodate the 1:n relationship.

Comment: That doesn't contradict my point: if a class is used with EF for `DbSet<T>` then it _should not_ be used as a Web-API DTO: they're very different things. For example, that `Asset`'s `int Id` property: Web-API will mark that as a required property because it's a non-nullable `int`, which means you can't use it as a request-body DTO for a "Create-new-Asset" request because the client cannot supply a value for the `Id` property because it's (presumably) generated by `IDENTITY`  in your database - do you see the problem there? Also, it means opening your application up to overposting attacks.

Comment: @Dai Apologies for the delayed response. I was on holiday last week. You are correct the AssetID and AssetAliasID fields are both IDENTITY in my database. I guess I understand the issue you outline here. But, I don't comprehend how to alter my code to resolve this issue. Might you post an answer with some code that might help to resolve this issue?